# C wrong answer of circular shift of a number

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, shift

The implementation of the right shift is:

```
unsigned int rotr(unsigned int value, int shift) {
    return (value >> shift) | (value << (sizeof(value) * 8 - shift));
}
```

but if value is `0x17=00010111` that result should be `0x8b=10001011` but the result is `0x8000000b`.

how to handle this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned int rotr(unsigned int value,int shift) {
    return (value >> shift) | (value << (sizeof(value) * 8 - shift));
}
int main()
{
  unsigned int a = 0x17;
  printf("%x",rotr(a,(unsigned)1));
}

=> 8000000b
```

Comment: The result you are getting is not 16bit, it is 32bit

Comment: You expect the result to be byte, but use int? sizeof(value) is 4, instead of 1. Hence sizeof(value)*4 is 32, so you shift 31bits to the left.

Comment: Hint: `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(unsigned int));`...

Comment: @JeffRSon At first I used plain 8 which means 1 * 8 as you said but the result was `0xb8b`

Comment: use unsigned chars if you want to shift 8 bits around, if you use `ints` you're going to get results in `int` sizes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the correct result of rotating `0x17` in a 32-bit integer: you start with

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00010111
```

and you end up with

```
10000000 00000000 00000000 00001011
```

If you would like to rotate an 8-bit number, use `uint8_t` instead of `int` as the function parameter:

```
uint8_t rotr(uint8_t value, int shift) {
    // No need to multiply by sizeof(value), because the type uint8_t forces it to be 1
    return (value >> shift) | (value << 8 - shift));
}
```

Comment: a question: how does the uint8_t cast the result before returning? because if parameter is uint8_t but function returns int, then the returned value will be `b8b`. but if function returns uint8_t then the returned value will be `8b` and correct.

Comment: where does this `b8b` come from?

Comment: @Pooya Since the return value is declared `uint8_t`, the last eight bits are taken from the `int` result of the `|` operation, and returned to the caller. This is intentional, because the "shift left" portion counts on truncating the bits beyond the `8*sizeof(value)`. Returning `int` would be wrong without an additional cast.